# invalid Json Object in Android

Tags: android, json

Can someone help me why my json is invalid even i use JSON Editor Online to check and it says my json is valid?
This is my json response:

```
08-31 08:02:43.921: W/System.err(4767): org.json.JSONException: Value {"ContactID":5,"AdminUnitID":0,"UserRoleID":0,"SecretQuestionID":0,"FirstName":"nhan2","LastName":"nguyen2","Title":"student","Email":"nhan@mail.com","ProfileURL":"test","InactiveDate":"\/Date(-62135568000000)\/","UserName":null,"Password":null,"SecretAnswer":null,"RegisterDate":"\/Date(-62135568000000)\/","LastLogin":"\/Date(-62135568000000)\/"} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my code:

```
LoginContact contact = null;
    @Override
    protected LoginContact doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject jObject = null;
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            request.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");               
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
            try
            {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                in.close();
                String result = sb.toString();
                jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                contact = new LoginContact(jObject);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return contact;
    }
```

Here is a code to return Json in my .NET web service:

```
List<Contacts> list = this.getAllContacts();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string Json = js.Serialize(list);
        return Json;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below class to parse your json file.

```
public class JSONParser {

public JSONParser() {

}

JSONObject jObj;
String json;
InputStream is = null;

public JSONObject getJsonFromUrl(String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("Json String : " + json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jObj;
}
```

}

Method from this class that is getJsonFromUrl is returned you JSONObject. Then Access your data from that object by iterating through JSONObject.

Now in your main class using following code.

```
JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
JSONObject j = p.getJsonFromUrl("Your json Url or paste your json data here");

// Here get your all data one by one from your jsonObject. In you case 

String contactID = j.getString("ContactID");
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey Jitesh, I updated my code following your direction, but i still got the same error java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: ok, so at first, i thought i may have some problem with datetime between .net and java, so i remove properties for date time, and i check my web service, the response returns:
    {"ContactID":5,"FirstName":"nhan2","LastName":"nguyen2","Title":"student","Email":"nhan@mail.com"}
It still says this cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Oh, I figured out, after i followed your direction, my string becomes 
"{\"ContactID\":5,\"FirstName\":\"nhan2\",\"LastName\":\"nguyen2\",\"Title\":\"student\",\"Email\":\"nhan@mail.com\"}"
So i just replaced invalid \ out, it works now, Thanks!!!

Comment: If this answer is useful for you then please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the string

```
Object object = jsonParser.parse(yourstring);

jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I got a class cast exception now. However, instead of using a library, can you explain to me why my json is not invalid even i already check it at http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ ?

Comment: To be more clear, i use JavaScriptSerializer in my rest web service to return json string

Comment: I just update my code including the web service and the use of JsonParser

Answer (score 1):

you should use this way:

```
JSONObject jArray = null;

 try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

  //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```